# Searching for the last instance of data in a list

Tags: c++, list, function, access-violation

I have an assignment to write a function that searches for the last instance of data (integer in this case) in a list. The function breaks with access violation on the line with if statement.

```
Node* List::SearchLast (int val)
{
    Node* pLast=NULL;
    Node* pNode=pHead;
    while (pHead!=NULL)
    {
        if (pNode->data==val)
            pLast=pNode;
        pNode=pNode->next;
    }
    return pLast;
}
```

I tried watching what happens with pNode.[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0eji.png) it becomes zero as it should.But [then](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxhBD.png) just passes the while statement. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want `pNode!=NULL` instead of `pHead!=NULL` in the `while`? Nothing ever modifies `pHead`.

Comment: change to `while(pNode != Null)`

Comment: @dlf Oh god, thanks. I'm such an idiot.

Comment: Ha! But at least you know it, right? :D I think we've all done worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` is an infinite loop, change to:

```
Node* List::SearchLast(int val)
{
    Node *pLast = NULL;
    Node *pNode = pHead;
    while (pNode != 0) {
        if (pNode->data == val) pLast = pNode;
        pNode = pNode->next;
    }
    return pLast;
}
```